# Not able to fetch record from Database

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jsp

I want to populate the textbox of my JSP page with the record which i'm trying to fetch.

**Here is the JSP Code**

```
<BODY> 
<jsp:useBean id="Stu_Info" class="org.student.entity.RegistrationStudent" scope="application"> 
<% 
enrollmentno=Stu_Info.getEnroll(); 

HibernateUtils utility=new HibernateUtils(); 
Session sessionn=utility.getSession(); 
Transaction tx=sessionn.beginTransaction(); 

List<StuAcadDetails> detail=sessionn.createCriteria(StuAcadDetails.class).add(Restrictions.idEq(enrollmentno)).list(); 


for(StuAcadDetails stuDetails:detail) 
{ 
attPrac=stuDetails.getAttPrac(); 
attThry=stuDetails.getAttThry(); 
branch=stuDetails.getBranch(); 
doj=stuDetails.getDoj(); 
overallAgg=stuDetails.getOverallAggr(); 
performance=stuDetails.getPerformance(); 
preSemPer=stuDetails.getPreSemPer(); 
semester=stuDetails.getSemester(); 
sessPer=stuDetails.getSessPer(); 
} 
tx.commit(); 
sessionn.close(); 
%>
```

I'm able to retrieve the primary key(enrollmentno) from applicationContext, but using that primary key, record is not getting pulled up. I tried to print the value but all I'm getting is "null/0". So what should i do to fetch the record and populate the textfield of my JSP page.

**HibernateUtils**

```
public class HibernateUtils { 

static SessionFactory sessionfactory; 

static 
{ 
Configuration cfg=new Configuration().configure("/org/student/hibernate.cfg.xml"); 
ServiceRegistry registry=new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry(); 
sessionfactory=cfg.buildSessionFactory(registry); 
} 

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() 
{ 
return sessionfactory; 
} 

public static Session getSession() 
{ 
return sessionfactory.openSession(); 
} 
}
```